# Blender Motion creation

Tags: python, bones

Is it possible for math function to be created in python, that could be used in the designing of animation? For example using sin or cosine for the motion of the bones .

Is this what most animators do when they create some of there animation or are they all using GUI to produce the desired result?

Comment: I don't know how to use it myself, but I've heard there's an addon called Animation Nodes that does this.

Comment: Thank you, I think this will work for my projects.